# Rule 195 of Ayelet Hashachar by the Malbim

Tags: jewish-books, acharonim, parshanut-theory

If one looks at [the Malbim's *Ayelet Hashachar*](//he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A8_%28%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%22%D7%9D%29), he gives 613 rules for interpreting the Torah. But [if you look at it carefully](//he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A8_%28%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%22%D7%9D%29/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%9B%D7%91), you'll notice that rule 195 is missing. What happened to this rule?

Comment: Isaiah 2, 7: ...וְאֵין קֵצֶה לְאֹצְרֹתָיו...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what Isaiah has to do with my question. Can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry Craig, I don't have an answer (though I searched) - it really is an interesting mystery. My comment was supposed to be a humorous allusion to this absence ("אין קצה" - i.e. "no rule 195").

Comment: @Cauthon, you might have solved the mystery. I have a theory that the Malbim left it out on purpose to prevent people from abusing his 613 rules and darshan Torah for themselves. Perhaps the Malbim used that pasik to do this. I am guessing that none of this is by accident.

Comment: Interesting suggestion :). I was surprised that I couldn't find mention of this anywhere, even though it is printed in the beginning of Vayikra in every Chumash with Malbim that I've seen.

Comment: Or perhaps rule 195 is that there is no rule 195.

Comment: Interestingly, no 55 is also missing from the first printing (Bucharest 1860) - https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990020310870205171/NLI but was added in later printings. So, maybe a printing error that was (unfortunately) never corrected?